# Wireless Printer Server recommendations?

Tags: wireless-networking, printer

My town library has a wireless network in place.  They want to relocate an existing USB printer connected to a PC to another location that's far away from any PCs.  So connecting the printer to PC via a very long USB cable is not a great solution.  The printer does not support WiFi only USB.

The only solution I see is to use a Wireless Print Server.  Does anyone have recommendations?  From reading a few reviews, these devices seem quirky and may not always work with every printer.

Besides a wireless print server, any other solutions?

Comment: It's not very clear on your question if this printer supports Wi-Fi. Could you please edit it?

Comment: Clarified based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience with WPS, Linksys make great products and I never had any issue with their WPS equipement.

I recommend you to check the WPSM54G that does a great job! Already installed a few for clients and it always work out straight out of the box with minimals configurations.

Check it out : http://www.linksysbycisco.com/CA/en/products/WPSM54G

Comment: I have one installed here at home - works great.

Answer (score 0):

Many wi-fi routers and modems increasingly sport a USB port which support anything from a printer to a flash drive.

I have re-purposed an older TP-Link router to an access point with a printer connected.

But remember- much like the print servers sold by Linksys/HP/TP-Link et al, these work on the 'wireless USB' solution using a software that needs to be installed on each computer.

I use an older HP MFD in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You say you're using "an existing USB printer". The model and specs of the printer are crucial here.

Specifically, if the printer supports a Page Description language like PCL5, PCL6 or PostScript, then just about any printserver will do the job. That includes USB printer ports on some routers.

However, if the printer is a modern, low-cost, "host-based" printer (which uses the host PC to convert the page into dots on the paper) then things become a lot more difficult. These printers are notoriously hard to network and will typically only work with printservers that specifically support the printer. Reputable printserver manufacturers have a list of supported printers. If your printer is not on the list, you must assume it will not work. Host-based printers come under a variety of names, including GDI, PCL3 (no relation to PCL5/6), LIDL, etc.

Note that most USB-only printers are host-based. If you can provide your printer's model number I may be able to update this answer with recommended printservers.